# Can a Directed acyclic graph have zero edges?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph, topological-sort

Suppose Graph G is a directed acyclic graph with 'n' no of vertices. Would this be a DAG if I remove all the edges from the graph and make it completely disconnected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph), a directed graph is just a set of vertices and a set of directed edges. A set can be empty, so you can have a directed graph with an empty set of edges. The same object would probably qualify as an undirected graph with no undirected edges as well. A graph with no edges cannot contain a cycle, so such a graph must be acyclic.